# operations on data of multiple txt. files in a folder

Tags: python

For some research I am analysing an area for precipitation and runoff. Everything works fine when I analyse one area (pd.read_csv), but I would like to analyse multiple (>10) areas at the same time without manually changing the file every time.
My goals in steps:

- 1. Operations on all txt files in folder A.
- 2. Operations on all txt files in folder B.
- 3. Operations on combination of matching files from folder A and B. For example, put the precipitation of area 5 and runoff of area 5 in a graph together.

**What I tried**

I figured that this can be done by using `for files in os.scandir(foldername)` and then start operations on all files in that folder, but my method is definitely wrong.

The first thing I like to do is to add a index in all of my files. I changed my path to "folderA" for this question. I tried it this way:

```
for files in os.scandir(r"C:folderA"):
    with open (file) in files:
        file.loc[:,'dt'] = file.to_datetime(file[['year', 'month', 'day']])
        file.index = file['dt']
        file.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day','Rain','dt']
        file.head()
```

This results in the error: FileNotFoundError

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-1641f38697a9> in <module>
      1 for files in os.scandir(r"C:\FolderA"):
----> 2     with open (file) in files:
      3         file.loc[:,'dt'] = file.to_datetime(file[['year', 'month', 'day']])
      4         file.index = file['dt']
      5         file.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day','Rain','dt']

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'
```

As you can see I can really use some help to get me started. I think that when I understand the process better, that I will be able to do the operations myself. In conclusion, my questions is how can I do operations automatically on the data of all txt. files in a folder?

Comment: I was about to say that `with open (file) in files:` was invalid syntax, but apparently it _is_ valid somehow, but it tries to access an _existing_ variable `file` instead of iterating over `files`. So maybe `file` is equal to `'C'` in your code? Please post the _full_ error message - that will pinpoint the exact line where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

To loop over all files in a directory, do this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(file_path) as file:
            # logic
```

make sure the path you give is correct